# Sharepoint online use the same new/display/edit forms for two or more libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to develop a Sharepoint online site to show inventory of every departments. Since I have several thousands of items, I separate the items into several libraries by departments. Each library will have the same columns.

Currently, I'm facing a problem of how to standard the new/display/edit forms for all libraries. Of cause I can use library template to do so. But what if I need to update the form, e.g. add a reference link or change the layout? Then I need to modify the form one by one for each library.

Is there any solutions that I can create one master form so that (1) it can be applied to two or more libraries, and (2) whenever the master form is changed, the change is automatically applied to the libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for Content Types.

At the Site Settings level, Create the columns you want.  Then create the Content type you want, called "Inventory" for example.  Add the columns to that Content Type.

Add the content type to each library.

- Library Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Allow Management of Content Types
- Remove the default content type from the library settings page

Now, you can update the columns at the site Content Type level, and it will publish to and update each library.

Comment: This method only works on default edit/display/update forms. What if I need to have the same customized form for all libraries?